I'm looking for a sci fi tv show that I watched a long time ago

a couple that may or may not actually be together, move into a gated community type of situation
everyone is very very friendly
the woman in the couple is pretending to be pregnant/or pretending to be one of them and is actually pregnant
the people in the town are very happy she is pregnant and highly recommend breastfeeding?

I think they are body snatchers or aliens pretending to be human
at one point they look into a garden and inside some sort of leafy vegetable there are human teeth growing inside

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  ("A long time ago" is pretty indeterminate; was it approximately 1980 or approximately 2015?)

Was it live action or animated?

In what country did you see this? What language was it in? Was it in color or black & white?

ah Im sorry, even though I watched it in the 2000s it could be older, as my parents watched their shows on discs with sharpie on it.
it was live action and in colour
